# How do I return mysql database evenly spaced columns and column titles vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've not been able to find much information on this.

How do I return database column titles and space column queried data evenly? 
I've been able to space data using Space() but the records vary in characters so the record data is returned staggered like this:

RS.Read() Returns
==================================================
3942 Associate Description Regular Hours OT Hours
343243543 Associate Description Regular Hours OT Hours

Code
===================================================
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
    Imports MySql.Data

```
MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbCon)
dbCon.Open()
DR = MySqlCmd.ExecuteReader
    While DR.Read
         TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & _
         DR.Item("DATE") & _
         Space(5) & DR.Item("JOB_NUMBER") & _
         Space(5) & DR.Item("ASSOCIATE") & _
         Space(5) & DR.Item("DESCRIPTION") & _
         Space(5) & DR.Item("REGULAR_HOURS") & _
         Space(5) & DR.Item("OT_HOURS") & _
         vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    End While
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at strings.rset and strings.lset. You will also have to use a monospaced font for your textbox. The more usual approach though would be to use a datagridview rather than a textbox.

Comment: I would use datagridview If I could, I'm using MySql db and VS Studio 2010 doesn't support mysql connector as a data source. I'll look into Rset and Iset.

Comment: I know nothing about MySQL but a very quick google seems to indicate you can return a dataset. You could then presumably bind that to a datagridview via a bindingsource in the normal way. Or, based on the code you already have, you could populate a grid in unbound mode. That said, LSet and RSet are the specific answer to the question you asked.